# Anyone have experience with the Tamron SP AF 70-200mm f/2.8 DI LD (IF) Macro?

Tags: nikon-d7000, telephoto, sports, tamron

I was planning to get the Nikon 70-200mm, but there is a big price difference compared to the Tamron.  I will use this for sport shooting. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The Tamron 70-200mm f/2.8 Di LD (IF) Macro lens is known to have fairly good image quality but very slow AF performance. Not exactly what you want to hear about a lens you are considering for sports/action photography. Here's the [review of the lens at The-Digital-Picture](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Tamron-70-200mm-f-2.8-Di-Macro-Lens-Review.aspx).

The newly released [Tamron 70-200mm f/2.8 SP Di VC](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Tamron-70-200mm-f-2.8-Di-VC-USD-Lens-Review.aspx) is better optically and much better in terms of focus speed. It also costs twice as much as the older lens, but is still just under 2/3 the price of the latest Nikon 70-200mm f/2.8G IF-ED AF-S VR II.

Comment: thank you for the link www.the-digital-picture.com this site is new for me cause im usually go to dpreview.com